# Change the edit action with devise with custom controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise with a custom controller (user controller, rather than devise controller)

I needed to change the `create` action, which works fine. It looks like this:

```rb
  def create
   super do |user|
      @patient = user.build_patient
      @patient.save
   end
  end
```

But when I try the same technique with the `edit` action, the instance variable seems to be `nil` when it's used in the view (it seems to set just fine in the controller when I use `byebug`/`binding.pry` to test it manually)

```rb
def edit
# binding.pry
  super do |user|
    if current_user.physician.stripe_details_submitted
      Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:secret_stripe_test_key]
      @stripe_account_dashboard_link = Stripe::Account.create_login_link(current_user.physician.stripe_account).url
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why right after I wrote the question. Here it is in case anyone else needs it.

While changing the create method uses `super` like this:

```
  def create
   super do |user|
     ...
   end
  end
```

use of `super` ***isn't*** necessary for the `edit` action (so just remove `super`):

```
def edit

    if current_user.physician.stripe_details_submitted
      Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:secret_stripe_test_key]
      @stripe_account_dashboard_link = Stripe::Account.create_login_link(current_user.physician.stripe_account).url
    end

end
```

And that works!